# Capture screenshots with a fixed aspect ratio

Tags: screenshot

Use case: I am making some demo videos for various software and need screenshots of the software. These should all have the same aspect ratio. Size can differ.

Question: Is there a screenshot tool for Ubuntu that allows selecting a region on the screen, but restricts the aspect ratio of that region?

Already tried: Spectacle does not appear to have any such functionality. I've also tried Shutter, which comes closer, as it allows specifying the default width and height of the region to screenshot. However I wish to be able to change the size of this region when making the screenshot, and there appears to be no way to doing that while preserving the aspect ratio.

Please note that I am not looking for an editing program that can change the aspect ratio of the screenshots after they where taken.

Comment: I would really like a way to do this as well, it seems like a no brainer for Shutter to add a checkbox that constrains the aspect ratio of the manual width and height values.

Answer (score 1):

From the terminal do:

```
shutter -s -e -o '/path/%T.png'
```

a screenshot dim area will appear. It would likely have the size of the last screenshot you have used. In order to change that size press the Shift key. A popup window will appear with the option to resize the window to whatever size you want. It's also possible to move the new resized window after that.
See shutter man for meaning of the -s -e -o %T parameters. Tested on Ubuntu 20.10

Answer (score 0):

In a first step, you could make a screenshot of the whole screen. Then open it in an image editing program like GIMP, and use its cutting tool to perform this task.